# How to control Pop Out pragmatically

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have an application where I upload an external website

in which I make and receive calls

the problem is that when I change the tab for example to see chat, or activity, ... my external site cuts the call

the solution is to keep the tab active in the background or use the pop-out,

to use the pop-out is there a way to control it in programming for example when I have an incoming call I open the pop-out directly?

thanks

Comment: Currently it is not possible to control pop-out a Tab using SDK programmatically. To achieve your requirements, we recommend you give your feedback in Teams Feedback Portal.

Comment: [Teams Feedback Portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)